# eTap Load Flow Analysis

Tags: power

In eTap, is there a possibility to run Load Flow analysis for multiple configurations of a one line diagram in a single iteration? This will save time taken for individual report generation and comparison.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SE!  But...what's eTap?  What's your project?  Do you have schematics, screenshots, or some other kind of graphics?  What have you tried so far and failed with?  With so few details, we can't possibly give you a good answer.  Please edit.

Comment: Also see here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  Thanks!

Comment: eTap is a Power Systems Software used in the industry.

Answer (score 1):

Load Flow analysis could be done iteratively using the Scenario Wizard in eTap. Source: ETAP Electrical Engineering Community in LinkedIn.